# Private docker registry in cloud-init.yaml

Tags: amazon-ec2, artifactory, autoscaling, docker-registry

I have a private docker registry. Usually I have to login to the client machine and type `docker login <private registry url>`

I would like to deploy an AWS auto scaling dockerized environment but I am not sure how to ensure the docker commands to pull an image uses our private docker registry only. I was thinking to have it in cloud-init.yaml and setup

```
- path: /root/.docker/config.json
  content: |
     {
      "auths": {
          "<private registry url>": {
              "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          }
      },
      "HttpHeaders": {
      "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/xyz (xyzzy)"
      }
  }
```

Is that the correct approach or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an S3 bucket to hold your json configuration for registry configuration and set it up on boot.